# Using [labeling] and [label-expression] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have:

- [1,366 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling+-label-expression) tagged only as [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling)
- [10 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/label-expression+-labeling) tagged only as [label-expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/label-expression)
- [9 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/label-expression+labeling) tagged as both [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) and [label-expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/label-expression)

Do we need both the [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) and [label-expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/label-expression) tags?

Comment: With the pro/con vote from answers at 6-0 I have proceeded to merge the [tag:label-expression] tag into the [tag:labeling] tag, leaving the former as a synonym.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Label expressions in various products can be written using various languages/parsers that are usually tagged on questions about writing them.

I think questions about labelling using an expression are best tagged with [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) and another tag for the language/parser used to write that expression, and I propose making the [label-expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/label-expression) tag a synonym of the [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) tag.